# How to enable GCM API in the Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I am trying to enable the GCM API in the google developer console, but it seems they have changed it. When I click Google Cloud Messaging on the API page, it now takes me to a firebase page where it says nothing about enabling it. Has anyone else found this problem recently?

Answer (score 6):

[image]
In your GDC:

1. Go to Dashboard.
2. Type Google Cloud Messaging in search box.
3. Choose GCM then Enable.

Not sure if this helps but check [GCM Setup page](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) too.

Answer (score 0):

GCM is now deprecated. And you are recommended to use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) .

Here is the link to the Firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com/

Just click on Create a new project and follow the instructions its quite self explanatory. But if you want step by step information i suggest you checkout the firecast videos in youtube they are a great starting point on how to use firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Ref https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#gcm-fcm

**Upgrading to Firebase**

**How do I add Firebase to an existing Google project?**

You may have existing projects managed through the Google Cloud console or the Google APIs console. By default, these projects are visible in the Firebase console, but are not considered to be Firebase projects.

To add Firebase to your existing project, click "Import Google Project" on the Firebase console landing page.